# Non-ORM viewset/serializer and browsable API form population

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a non-ORM endpoint with d-r-f with a view set subclassing GenericViewSet and a custom serializer.  Everything works fine, and since I'm using GenericViewSet, I'm getting the editable form at the bottom of the browsable API.  But (for example) in the detail view, the PUT/PATCH form is not being auto-populated the way the regular ORM-based view sets do.  Is there something that I need to override and do that manually?  Or something I'm otherwise missing to get that working?

Oh, and these aren't non_field_errors or anything - all of the serializer types are pretty basic.  Just not getting any autofill.

Sample code since it was requested - a simple serializer:

```
class CircuitNodeBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    pk = serializers.IntegerField()
    layer = serializers.IntegerField()
    layer_description = serializers.CharField()
```

And a non-model view set that overrides the usual methods:

```
class CircuitExampleConnectionViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Circuit.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CircuitNodeBaseSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        nodes = list()
        for c in self.queryset:
            n = get_circuit_node_by_pk(c.id)
            nodes.append(n)
        serializer = CircuitNodeBaseSerializer(nodes, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        c = get_circuit_node_by_pk(pk)
        serializer = CircuitNodeBaseSerializer(c, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

...etc...
```

Everything is working just fine, but I'm not getting any auto-population in the forms - either the html form or the raw data/json block.

Comment: Could you post some code ? I guess you already override some methods since I don't think having a custom serializer is enough.